# iOS UITableViewCell needs to be pressed twice to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that sometimes requires you touch it twice to select a cell.

More specifics:

- Two touches are needed only after the table has been scrolled all the way up or all the way down.
- Only the second touch even calls `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.
- When the table opens in the natural "scrolled up position", cells are indeed selectable with just one touch.
- If you scroll just a little bit (not all the way down/up), the cells will select with just one touch.
- If cells do not fill the whole table and scrolling is not required, it works fine.
- Go all the way to the top or bottom and you have to touch twice.

I have a feeling that the first touch is really making the UITableViewCells selectable or is activating the table in some way.

Things I have checked:

- My code definitely doesn't call `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` anywhere.
- No `UIGestureRecognizers` are using `setCancelsTouchesInView:`.

Other settings on the table:

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.tableView.bounces = NO;
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

What's causing this?

---

## Update

Oddly enough, setting `self.tableView.bounces = YES;` fixed the problem.

I am still looking into the root cause in case anyone has a better answer. Obviously I would like for the table not to bounce, but not if it costs key functionality.

Comment: Is it the same in simulator?

Comment: This is occurring in both the simulator and on a device.

Comment: "Things I have checked:

My code definitely doesn't call didDeselectRowAtIndexPath anywhere." why not? isnt this how its normally done?

Comment: Maybe... while it's possible I'm doing cell de-selection in an unorthodox way, that doesn't account for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` not being called at all after the first tap when nothing has been done to the table but it being scrolled all the way down.

Comment: added detail: If cells do not fill the whole table and scrolling is not required, it works fine.

Comment: Wild guess - perhaps you are doing some network call in the main thread to download some data for the table view, and the ui is blocked while that is happening?

Comment: There are network calls and location calls, but even when I wait until both are done, the issue persists. The calls might be making the table inactive somehow...

Comment: Are you adding `UIGestureRecognizers` to the table view and/or cells? In general, these don't play well with each other. Especially, tap gestures can be problematic.

Comment: Not directly to the table. I did add them to it's superview though.

Answer (score 9):

May be you implemented didDeselect instead of didSelect?

Comment: good one! Not the first time this happened to me :-) thanks Vũ Ngọc Giang

Answer (score 4):

**Swift:**

Once a cell gets tapped, it also gets selected, try deselecting it as soon as it was tapped.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    }
```

Other things to check also are `delaysContentTouches` and `canCancelContentTouches` properties.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 4

You need to surround your updates with beginUpdates() and endUpdates()

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // get current cell
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YourCustomCell

    // change the value

    // Update the tableView
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to disable delaysContentTouches:

```
tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```