# didSelectItemAt for UICollectionView is only calling on double touch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, segue

I'm facing a weird issue in `UICollectionView` using iOS11 emulator. In my project i have a `UICollectionView` with `UIImageView` as cells and I've created segue as Triggered Segues for cells by dragging it to a view controller. It was working great but know the segue is not performing so i decided to remove the segue from cells Triggered Segues and I created a segue from my view controller to the destination view controller and performed segue from code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCell
    if let url = URL(string: "\(StringResources.serverAddress)/Content/images/Files/Thumb/\(photos[indexPath.row])") {
        cell.image.downloadFrom(url: url)
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("clicked")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "PhotoSegue", sender: collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath))
}
```

but it's not working either and there is no clicked printed in console. I've checked cell and `UIImageView` user interaction also `UICollectionView` delegate is ok. How can i fix it?

---

edit: I've found the problem. It's only calling when I'm double clicking on cell

Comment: could you share more info about your cell?

Comment: it has an `UIImageView` only @jvrmed

Comment: yes I've mentioned that it has been set to my view controller and i did it again in code but didn't help @OzgurVatansever

Comment: is it a `UIImageView` or a `UICollectionViewCell` with an `UIImageView` inside?

Comment: Post your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` code. Also, in your view controller's `viewDidAppear(_:)` method, add code `print("collection view data source = " + myCollectionView.dataSource)` and check what is displayed.

Comment: As stated by @OzgurVatansever make sure you have your delegate and datasource set also you will need `override` in front of your function as well.

Comment: it's a `UICollectionViewCell` with a `UIImageView` inside @jvrmed

Comment: I've edited my question and the output is my view controller @DuncanC

Comment: is it possible to scroll your collectionView? Is there any custom UIGestureRecognizer over your view or cell?

Comment: yes it's scrollable @jvrmed

Comment: there is no need to override and when I'm adding it shows me an error @MwcsMac

Comment: is your `downloadFrom` method performed in a background thread? the download could be blocking the UI

Comment: yes it's using `URLSession.shared.dataTask` for download @jvrmed

Comment: did you set the delegate of the CollectionView in the storyboard as the File's owner?

Comment: please read the last line of question @DuncanC

Comment: @Amir_P You should answer your own question and then accept it as soon as you're allowed so that your readers can learn the solution.

Comment: i couldn't foul the solution. i just found the problem @DuncanC

Comment: @Amir_P What is the fix for this. I m facing this issue too.

Comment: I'm not sure if our cases are similar but for me the problem was that I was adding an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the whole view to dismiss the keyboard and removing that fixed the problem @Rajesh

Comment: Yes, Same issue. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some things that you could check and once all of them are in order it should work:

1. Check that your `UICollectionView` has both delegate and dataSource set.
2. Check that your `UIImageView` ***userInteractionEnabled*** property is set to **false**.

According to documentation:

> Image views ignore user events by default. Normally, you use image views only to present visual content in your interface. If you want an image view to handle user interactions as well, change the value of its isUserInteractionEnabled property to true. After doing that, you can attach gesture recognizers or use any other event handling techniques to respond to touch events or other user-initiated events.

4. Check that both `UICollectionView` and parent have. ***userInteractionEnabled*** property is set to **true**.
5. Check that there are no other `UIGestureRecognizers` catching your touch event.
6. Check that there are no network requests freezing your UI.

Considering the information that you provided, I would try to remove the `UIImageView` from the cell and make sure that the cell touch is working before adding more elements.

Comment: it's not working. I've edited my post please read the last line

Comment: you need to share more information, your cell class and possibly your controller too, there is another element that is interfering in your views for sure

Comment: is there any other _UICollectionViewDelegate_ method that you are implementing?

Comment: no it's only section and item in section the cell for item and did select item

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351819/ios-uitableviewcell-needs-to-be-pressed-twice-to-call-didselectrowatindexpath

Comment: by double click i mean multi touch click @jvrmed

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that I was adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to dismiss the keyboard and that was catching touch events.

```
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

Comment: told you there was another `UITapGestureRecognizer` blocking your events on item number 5 of my answer

Comment: yes you were right sorry i forgot to accept answer @jvrmed

Comment: Finally, This should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be due to the fact that collection views have a ***didSelectItemAt*** method as well as a ***didDeselectItemAt*** method which alternate per click. This could explain why it only works on a double click (one click calls didSelect, the next calls didDeselect).

A quick (but not elegant) solution could be to implement your ***didDeselectItemAt*** and just use it to call the ***didSelectItemAt***